# Change the alternative label and description for image widget

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to modify the label and description text on the alternative input of an image widget in Drupal 8.  I came across solutions using hook_field_widget_form_alter for D7, but can't seem to get this working for D8.  Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  // If this is an image field type of instance 'field_image_top'
  if ($context['widget'] instanceof \Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ImageWidget) {
    // Loop through the element children (there will always be at least one).
    foreach (Element::children($element) as $key) {
      // Add the new process function to the element.
      $element[$key]['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process';
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  // Change the title field label and description
  $element['title']['#title'] = 'NEW TITLE';
  $element['title']['#description'] = 'SOME NEW DESCRIPTION HERE.';

  // Return the altered element
  return $element;
}
```

Basically the `foreach (Element::children($element) as $key)` isn't finding any children.  However from the page output there is clearly an input for the "Alternative text".

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your post.
It's helped me to alter "alt" & "title" fields.

This works for me :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $context) {
  // If this is an image field type of instance
  if ($context['widget'] instanceof \Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ImageWidget) {
    $element['#process'][] = 'MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_image_field_widget_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {

  if (isset($element['alt'])) {
    $element['alt']['#title'] = 'MY ALT IMAGE';
    $element['alt']['#description'] = '';
  }
  if (isset($element['title'])) {
    $element['title']['#title'] = 'MY TITLE IMAGE';
    $element['title']['#description'] = '';
  }

  // Return the altered element
  return $element;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8 uses twig as template renderer different from D7 wich uses PHP. Can't be ported as it is from drupal 7, but form alter hook still exist.

In the D8 docs looks like Element:children gets all children element, except for those with #key. Maybe this is what you looking for.

> The children of a element array are those key/value pairs whose key does not start with a '#'. See drupal_render() for details.

I would type var_dump($element) to check it. If fails as an empty element, you could try to modify your data with preprocess field hook.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it's true the element doesn't contain any keys not starting with "#". So now it makes sense that Element:children doesn't return anything.  What I do find strange it that it doesn't have children, so where is the alt text element?